# ShareKit Twitter integration

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, sharekit

I installed ShareKit for Twitter Support in my app. I registered all keys and urls and so on. But my problem is: In my app the user sees sentences. I want that the user can tweet this sentence. What method do I have to write. I've got:

```
-(IBAction)tweetSentence {

 NSString* message = [[sprueche objectAtIndex: spruecheCount] stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nhttp://projectkeecks.com"] ;

}
```

What do I have to add?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial on getsharekit.com
But now I've got:

```
- (void)myButtonHandlerAction
{
    // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
    NSString *someText = @"This is a blurb of text I highlighted from a document.";
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    // Display the action sheet
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

But I've got no navigationController
How can I do the "display the action sheet" part in the interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `[actionSheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];` you can use `[actionSheet showInView:self.view];`. You need not have a navigation controller in this case.